# C++ templates not defined in header / linker error

Tags: c++, templates, linker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

I just came across something that I failed to understand.
I had a problem at the linking stage in the following case.

```
//header file
class A 
{
    template<class T>
    std::weak_ptr<T> GetSomethingFromSomeWhere(const char* Id);
};

//cpp file
template<class T>
std::weak_ptr<T> A:GetSomethingFromSomeWhere(const char* id)
{
   //A method with the right stuff inside and the right return statement
   ...
}


//Another class
class B
{
};

//main.cpp
int main ()
{
   A a;
   auto pB = a.GetSomethingFromSomeWhere<B>( "id" );
}
```

This didn't compile, during linking I have something of this kind :

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::weak_ptr A::GetComponentFromName(char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I fixed it by defining the template method directly in the header file.

Should I always define template method in the header ? Why ?
I am on OSX and use clang++ with XCode if that can be of any help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template definition needs to be visible to the code using it. Otherwise linker errors will be generated.
There are different workarounds for situations like that:

[Read This](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl.html)

Comment: I thought it could make the linking on is own. I got that wrong, thanks for the link.